# For deleting a node in a linked list if I use memmove() (in C) will it be more efficient?

Tags: c, singly-linked-list, memory-efficient, memmove

Every example I encountered in internet about deleting a node in a linked list, they use this method for deleting the first node:

```
Algorithm to delete first node of Singly Linked List
%%Input:  head of the linked list
Begin:
    If (head != NULL) then
        toDelete ← head
        head ← head.next
        unalloc (toDelete)
    End if
End
```

In this code they are freeing up the memory region after they removed the 1st node from there list.
But I'm using memove() to delete the 1st node of the linked list.

```
...
if (key == 1){ 
    memmove(head, head->next, sizeof(node));
    return;
}
...
```

So, when I use the memmove() does it automatically frees the memory region??
And is my code is more efficient??

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: You have just created a memory leak by moving your 2nd node data to the address of the first. You have lost the address of the 1st node in that case. Calling free on `head` will now delete the original 2nd node with no way to free what was the original `head` node.

Comment: So, can i say that there is just one way to delete a node

Comment: No, there are several ways to do it, but all involve freeing the node you are deleting, see the `del_node()` function here [Singly Linked List (node only, no wrapper)](https://pastebin.com/5MPLU4wB) For why it is best it use both the address of the pointer and pointer, See [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: The original 1st node is still the head of the list, but now contains the data the 2nd node did (its original data being overwritten).  The old 2nd node has not been freed, but the pointer to it in 1st is gone because your 1st node now points to the (original) 3rd node instead.  So there is a memory leak, from the old 2nd node not being freed.  And it's probably not faster.

Answer (score -1):

In your code *head* is a pointer which is a scalar so it will not be faster to use *memmove* than a simple assignment. The *memmove* function can be beneficial when copying larger objects.